# Can I listen to a document content that has not already been created?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

My requirement is the followin, I need to listen to a document value that has not yet been created.

My use case is this, I launch a cloud function that writes to an specific path in my firestore database, then from android I attach a listener to that value that has not yet been created, and then when its created a launch the logic with the data that has been placed at the database.

```
db.collection("home").document("homeTest/light_id").get().addOnCompleteListener {
            if(it.isSuccessful){
                progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                btnHomeLight.isEnabled = true
               }
            }else{
                Log.e("Exception",""+it.exception)
            }
        }
```

At the time I have this code in my `onCreate()` the `light_id` has not yet been created at the database

After I trigger my function, that `light_id` is beign created and It should enable the `btnHomeLight`

But I'm getting this error

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid document
>   reference. Document references must have an even number of segments,
>   but home/hometest/light_id has 3

My database structure is this one

```
*Collection* 
  |__home
    |__ *Document*
       |___homeTest
           |__ light_id : "Random_generated_ID"
```

Is my reference the problem ?

Since Im under the collection **home** and inside the **document(homeTest/light_id)** that should fetch that certain value.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by doing this

```
 val docRef = db.collection("home").document("homeTest")
        docRef.addSnapshotListener { documentSnapshot, firebaseFirestoreException ->
 if(!documentSnapshot?.getString("light_id").isNullOrEmpty()){
...
}
```

By the way, I dont really know if this is the best approach to do it.

If there is a better way I would be glad to hear about